# How do I convert a date in PHP?

Tags: php, date-conversion

How can I convert this date:

`2009-12-21 10:38:07`

to a more readable date, like `22 December 2009 - 10:38`
?

Comment: TravisO, I don't agree with the rtfm tag...
You get a much better (and faster) answer by asking the question than by reading the manual.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`date`](http://be.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function with [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
$strDate = "2009-12-21 10:38:07";
echo date('d F Y - H:i', strtotime($strDate));
```

Comment: sounds like you didn't really have faith in it :-p

Comment: hehe i was just very impressed :-D

Answer (score 0):

```
// Prints: July 1, 2000 is on a Saturday
echo "July 1, 2000 is on a " . date("l", mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2000));
```